# Unable to install flex module in angular application

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am implementing a sample application in **Angular** with **AngularMaterial** and **FlexLayout** .

I have successfully installed and implementing Angular Material Components.I have also installed Flex using the below command

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout --save
```

But when I am running my application I am getting the following warning message in my Eclipse Terminal as shown below

[image]

And I am also getting the following **error** in my console.

[image]

**Below shown is `package.json` file**

```json
{
  "name": "angular-material-demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.16",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "primeng": "^2.0.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-ide": "^0.9.38",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

I tried doing the below steps also.

```
Edited package.json: Had to change my version for @angular/compiler-cli. In my case I had to bring it back to 5.2.0, as it somehow got to 5.2.10.

Deleted the node_modules directory.

Ran: npm install

Installed: npm install @angular/flex-layout.
```

But again i ran in different errors. I also tried changing the version of flex from `"@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.16"` to `"@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.12"` in package.json file but I am still getting these errors.

Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please do not use images to convey textual information. [Edit] your question to replace them with the respective code. Additionally, questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Without this, your question is off-topic and liable to be closed. Please construct a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it.

Comment: Your images are hard for me to read but I have Flex Layout installed here and you can see how it is wired up.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-multi-queries.  Be sure to import it into app.module.ts.  After that it should be easy. Also, if you have a lazy loaded child module it should be imported into there, unless something in Angular changed and I haven't noticed it.